# How to Maintain React Functionality for Overlays on Fullscreen Video Players in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overlay

I'm developing a Chrome extension with React that overlays custom UI elements on top of video players across various websites. The extension works as expected in standard view, but I encounter issues when the video enters fullscreen mode. My overlay gets pushed to the background, behind the fullscreen video, making it invisible to the user.

To address this, I've implemented a workaround where I dynamically insert the overlay into the DOM tree of the fullscreen element, effectively bringing the overlay to the foreground. While this solves the visibility issue, it introduces a new problem: the loss of React's event handling capabilities (e.g., onClick) on the overlay's elements. It seems like once the overlay is manually inserted into the DOM, React no longer manages these elements, and thus, the React-specific event handlers stop working.

Here's an example of how I'm adding the overlay to the fullscreen element:

```
if (fullscreenElement && canvasParentRef.current) {
  fullscreenElement.appendChild(canvasParentRef.current);
}
```

Questions:

How can I add my React-based overlay to a fullscreen video in a way that keeps the React functionality intact, especially for event handlers like onClick?
Is there a more React-friendly approach to ensure that overlays remain functional and interactive atop fullscreen video players within a Chrome extension?

PS: Not a native english speaker. Used chatgpt to rephrase properly

Comment: Create a custom media player. If you request fullscreen on a HTML video element the video element covers the monitor.

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for the reply. my extension sits on top of other video elements. if i change their media player it'll be similar to destroying their code right?

Comment: I have no experience using React. I would just create the UI and instead of requesting fullscreen on a video element, request full screen for the entire HTML page, with your UI the only HTML in the full screen view.

Comment: @guest271314 yes i am requesting on the entire html page. The thing is this UI is bit complex and it has lot of moving parts, so i need react components and its life cycle methods for this to properly manage and its working properly when its not in full screen. But once I add it to dom when user goes full screen, none of the react methods are working.

Comment: I can help with the extension, HTML, media, and DOM parts. Can't help with React.